# Carousel inside of Modal Not Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've worked with modals and carousels before, but I can't crack this one. I've got an image grid and I'd like each image to open a bootstrap modal window and be able to carousel through the images.

I've spent time on this site: https://noreiller.github.io/bootstrap-modal-carousel/modal-carousel.html but I can't get it to work.

I'm taking over an existing app at work, so there's extra code in here for other things that 'might be needed later', so I've left it in. I think there's something there that's breaking it.

**Here are the libraries I'm using:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/framework.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap-theme.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="scripts/jqueryui.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap-modal-carousel.js"/></script/>

<script src="scripts/custom.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/framework.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/framework.launcher.js"></script>
```

**Javascript Modal call to open on image click:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.modalImg').on('click',function()
    {
        var sr=$(this).attr('src');
        $('innerModal').sttr('src',sr);
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
});

</script>
```

**And here's the modal and carousel code:**

```
    <div class="flex-container1">
    <div class="imGrid1">

        <!-- Parts Depot -->

        <div class="flex-item1 group1">
            <!-- Image to Trigger Modal -->
            <a href="#myModal" class="modalImg image-border image-border" data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/map/small/parts-depot-sm.jpg"></a>

            <div class="image-caption-box">
                <a href="#myModal" class="content-thumb" data-slide-to="0" draggable="false" data-toggle="modal"> 
                    <p>Parts Depot</p>
                    <p class="plus-icon">+</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
    </div>
```

Here's the result. The images load in on top of each other. In another iteration, I had the images switching but they would switch back after they were clicked.

Thanks very much for any help!

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMlLk.png)

Comment: There is not enough code here really to comment on. You "provide" the modal and carousel code but there isnt any modal or carousel.

https://i.gyazo.com/1b3087f396d5b291aefc0fb79ed52e1e.png

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the rest of my original comment got cut off. It ended up being some previous JS libraries that were controlling the carousel. Once I deleted those the carousel worked fine. Thanks for taking a look though!